# Magento shipping cart rule: add new condition

Tags: magento

Is it possible to create a new rule condition where i can use grand total for comparision?.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to watch if you can extend default behaviour here:

```
(mage root)/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/*
```

For Shopping rules and

```
(mage root)/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Rule/Condition/*
```

for Catalog rules.